# How can I cut a string in bash ignoring escaped delimiters?

Tags: regex, bash, csv, delimiter, cut

I am cutting a string from a csv file using comma as delimiter. Is there a way to add an option to the delimiter to ignore certain strings containing the delimiter?

I want to ignore all commas that are written inside quotation marks.

Example:

```
    asdf,1337,"asdf, asdf"
```

should become

```
    asdf
    1337
    asdf, asdf
```

and NOT

```
    asdf
    1337
    "asdf,
     asdf"
```

Comment: Use a language with a proper CSV parser. CSV can be surprisingly tricky to parse, and that wheel has long since been invented.

Answer (score 2):

This awk codes should help:

```
awk '{$0=$0","; while($0) { match($0,/ *"[^"]*" *,|[^,]*,/); 
             field=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH);
             gsub(/^ *"?|"? *,$/,"",field); 
             print field; $0=substr($0,RLENGTH+1)  }}' file
```

with your example:

```
kent$ echo 'asdf,1337,"asdf, asdf"'|awk '{$0=$0",";
while($0) {
  match($0,/ *"[^"]*" *,|[^,]*,/)
  field=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  gsub(/^ *"?|"? *,$/,"",field) 
  print field
  $0=substr($0,RLENGTH+1)  
}}'
asdf
1337
asdf, asdf
```

Comment: `awk -vRS='"' -vORS="" '(NR%2){gsub(/,/,"\n")}1'`